# Pass data in UIPageViewController Swipe

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller, pass-data

I am currently developping a fantasy football application. This is below a part of my storyboard ;[image: Storyboard] . I am using a container view embedded in a boarding pager (UIPageViewController) wich is used to swipe between two sceens "CreateTeamOne" and "CreateTeamTwo" . When I am in screen "CreateTeamTwo" , I select a player from the tableview and get his firstname and price (I know how to do that) , but when I swipe back to "CreateTeamOne" , I need to pass data to it and fill the labels DarkGrey and red [image: labels] with data of the player . I putted the values in an NSObject and when I do "print" in "CreateTeamTwo",they are filled correctly but when I use them in "CreateTeamOne" , it returnes empty values . how to do it ? thank you in advance.